# ggplot: gradient scale to diverge on specific break

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I have this data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = 1:10,
                 value = c(seq(from = 0.5, to = 3.2, length.out = 9), Inf))
```

which I want to plot with a gradient colour scale highlighting three break values:

```
breaks <- c(0.5,1,3.2)
```

I want the `white` colour to highlight my middle breaking value (that is `1`) and then the other two to increase in intensity as they reach the two tails of the distribution. Yet this will plot

```
require(ggplot)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,colour=value)) + geom_point(size=10) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("red","white","blue"),
                         breaks = breaks, labels = format(breaks))
```

[image]

with `white` centered on the mean/median value (`1.85`). I don't understand what's the point in declaring break points then.

Answer (score 18):

You could use `scale_colour_gradient2` instead of `scale_colour_gradientn`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y,colour=value)) + 
  geom_point(size=10) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = "blue", midpoint = 1, breaks = breaks) +
  theme_bw()
```

this gives:

[image]

Comment: If you had some time, would you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73711073/using-a-custom-gradient-fill-based-on-two-different-columns ? Your answer got me closer but I cannot get the labels on the right break value.